# xampp server not running mysql

Tags: xampp

```
2:18:47 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
2:18:47 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing 
dependencies, 
2:18:47 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by 
another method.
2:18:47 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
2:18:47 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
2:18:47 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
2:18:47 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

I try to run my MySQL from the XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.2, but it stops a bit after I hit Start. It says it's running for a solid second, then crashes. I tried changing its ports, but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have admin privileges (Right click on xampp exe, navigate to properties, check  run program as administrator under 'Compatibility' tab).

Then try starting the xampp control panel and click the green check mark to uninstall the MySQL module, then re-install. I would restart the computer after this to end any processes. If you have multiple instances of xampp, it's gonna cause issues.